# Extract data from axios body array buffer response

Tags: node.js, file, axios, request, zlib

I am calling an API that returns a gzip file in it's body. The problem I am having is I don't know how to extract specific data from that csv file as I need to use it further in my code. This is my code:

```
const response = await axios.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: api,
        decompress: true,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }).then(resp => {
        zlib.gunzip(resp.data,(err,output) => {
          console.log(output);
        })
      });
```

The console log in the zlib callback displays the file as I want it but i don't know how to assign that value to response once the gunzip is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the variable response to be set to output? If so you can just return output using an intermediary variable. I just called it out, but of course you can rename it to whatever seems fitting. Of course, you also need to handle the error cases, which I did not do below, but that should be a relatively easy task.

```js
const response = await axios.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: api,
        decompress: true,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }).then(resp => {
        let out;
        zlib.gunzip(resp.data,(err,output) => {
          out = output;
        })
        return out;
      });
```

Above the const `response` is set to the variable `output` in the gunzip func.